Question regarding inverse of exponential function
This question is in the context of the following problem
Find the inverse of the function
$$f:(-\infty, 1] \rightarrow \Biggr[\frac{1}{2}, \infty\Biggr], \text{ where } f(x) = 2^{x(x-2)}$$
I proceeded for the solution as follows
$$y = 2^{x(x-2)}$$
$$x^2 - 2x = \log_2y$$
$$x^2 - 2x - \log_2y = 0$$
$$x = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \log_2 y}$$
After this however my and the books solutions from which the question is taken diverged, i went on to create a piecewise function for both cases $x$ negative or positive, however the book did not do so and the answer for this is in the book is
$$f^{-1}(x) = 1 - \sqrt{1 + \log_2x}$$
Is their any reason to do so, any help would be appreciated!

There are two branches as in your solution. The book may have chosen 1 for simplicity

You can not have an inverse function on a non-injective function.  If $f(x) = f(y) = w;x\ne w$ then it is not clear whether $f^{-1}(w)$ should but $x$ or $y$.  In this case the domain is specifically restricted to $(-\infty, 1]$.   Thus if $y=f(x)$ and we continue to $x=1\pm \sqrt {1 + \log_2 y)$ w must have $x \le 1$.  As $1 +\sqrt{1 + \log_2y} > 1$ when $y> 1$ we must ignore it.

please do not tag such questions as [functional-analysis]. Use [functions] instead. Thanks!

Notice that $f^{-1}$ is a function whose range must be the domain of $f$, that is, $(-\infty,1]$. As $\sqrt{1+\log_2x}$ is non-negative, we have $1+\sqrt{1+\log_2x}\geq 1$, and this is not a possible inverse.
Therefore, the correct 'branch' is $f^{-1}(x)=1-\sqrt{1+\log_2x}$.

Thanks for the answer!
